# How can I add two image side by side in php?

Tags: php, html, css

This is my code :
I would like to add tree image side to side width 300px height 300px and that when you click on the iomage it will redirect them to a new page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<Title> Services </Title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</Head>
<body>
<div>
<h2> <div style=text-align:center;"> <img src="images/banner-services.jpg" alt="banner-services" /> </h2>
<h2 style=text-align:center;> <b> Select The Type of Dance You Would Like to Buy </b> </h2>
<br>
<a href="bachata.php">
    <div style="width:300px;height:300px;background-image:url('images/bachata-logooo.jpg');">
    <div style=text-align:center;"> Bachata
    </div>

    <a href="salsa.php">
    <div style="width:300px;height:300px;background-image:url('images/salsa-logooo.jpg');">
    <div style=text-align:center;"> salsa-logooo
    </div>

    a href="merengue.php">
    <div style="width:300px;height:300px;background-image:url('images/merengue-logooo.jpg');">
    <div style=text-align:center;"> merengue-logooo
    </div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Give `style="display:inline-block;"` to the `<a>` tags. Do note that this won't be responsive and unless the resolution is above (at least) 900px the blocks will overflow onto another line.